# Extra error message by JSON Schema validator when if-else is there

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

Here is my JSON Schema(hypothetical, as I cannot share my actual one) and the JSON. The if-then-else condition is like:

at a time only one (1) out of three (3) country can appear to define statistics.

Schema

```
    {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "year",
            "country",
            "statistics"
        ],
        "definitions": {
        "statisticsUsa": {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "statisticsUsa"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "type"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "statisticsUsa"
              }
            }
          }
        },
            "statisticsFinland": {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "statisticsFinland"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "type"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "statisticsFinland"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "statisticsGermany": {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "statisticsGermany"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "type", "literacy"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "statisticsGermany"
              },
              "literacy": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        },
        "properties": {
            "year": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "country": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "USA",
                    "FINLAND",
                    "GERMANY"
                ]
            },
            "statistics": {

                "type": "array",
                "allOf": [{
                        "if": {
                            "contains": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "enum": [
                                            "statisticsUsa"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "not": {
                                "contains": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "type": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "enum": [
                                                "statisticsFinland",
                                                "statisticsGermany"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },"errorMessage" :"Only USA applicable at a time for statistics"
                    },
                    {
                        "if": {
                            "contains": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "enum": [
                                            "statisticsFinland"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "not": {
                                "contains": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "type": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "enum": [
                                                "statisticsUsa",
                                                "statisticsGermany"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },"errorMessage" :"Only Finland applicable at a time for statistics"
                    },
                    {
                        "if": {
                            "contains": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "enum": [
                                            "statisticsGermany"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "not": {
                                "contains": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "type": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "enum": [
                                                "statisticsUsa",
                                                "statisticsFinland"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },"errorMessage" :"Only Germany applicable at a time for statistics"
                    }

                ],
                "minItems": 1,
                "items": {
                    "anyOf": [{
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/statisticsUsa"
                        },
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/statisticsFinland"
                        },
                        {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/statisticsGermany"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Json 1

```
    const Ajv = require('ajv');
    const ajv = new Ajv({
        allErrors: true,
        jsonPointers: true
    });

    const schema1 = require("./sof.json");
    require('ajv-errors')(ajv /*, {singleError: true} */);
    const data = {
      year: "2000",
      country: "USA",
      statistics: [
        {"type":"statisticsUsa"},
        {"type":"statisticsFinland"}
      ]
    }

    let valid = ajv.validate(schema1, data); //schema, data
    if (!valid) {
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(ajv.errors,null,2)}`);
    }
```

Here, I can see 2 errors as part of the array, when I have 2 countries. My question is, being 'finland' cannot have with 'USA', the error for "Only USA applicable at a time for statistics" is NOT acceptbale, as it satisfies the condition. But, The error for Findland is acceptable.

```
    [
      {
        "keyword": "errorMessage",
        "dataPath": "/statistics",
        "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/0/errorMessage",
        "params": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "keyword": "not",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/0/then/not",
              "params": {},
              "message": "should NOT be valid"
            },
            {
              "keyword": "if",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/0/if",
              "params": {
                "failingKeyword": "then"
              },
              "message": "should match \"then\" schema"
            }
          ]
        },
        "message": "Only USA applicable at a time for statistics"
      },
      {
        "keyword": "errorMessage",
        "dataPath": "/statistics",
        "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/1/errorMessage",
        "params": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "keyword": "not",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/1/then/not",
              "params": {},
              "message": "should NOT be valid"
            },
            {
              "keyword": "if",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/1/if",
              "params": {
                "failingKeyword": "then"
              },
              "message": "should match \"then\" schema"
            }
          ]
        },
        "message": "Only Finland applicable at a time for statistics"
      }
    ]
```

Also, if I add 'Germany' in JSON as,

```
{
  year: "2000",
  country: "USA",
  statistics: [
    {"type":"statisticsUsa"},
    {"type":"statisticsFinland"},
    {"type":"statisticsGermany"}
  ]
}
```

it throws 3 errors as part of the array (See below). Why?

1. Technically, the schema validator should stop at 2nd item and should ignore the 'Germany' in the error array as it finds 'Findland' entry is violating the if-else conditions.
2. Also, does schema-validator takes each item from 'statistics' array (from the JSON) and checks the conditions within 'allOf' for every run and that's why 3 error entries in the array. Is my understanding correct. (If you see the first error array above, it has 2 only entries)

```
    [
      {
        "keyword": "errorMessage",
        "dataPath": "/statistics",
        "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/0/errorMessage",
        "params": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "keyword": "not",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/0/then/not",
              "params": {},
              "message": "should NOT be valid"
            },
            {
              "keyword": "if",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/0/if",
              "params": {
                "failingKeyword": "then"
              },
              "message": "should match \"then\" schema"
            }
          ]
        },
        "message": "Only USA applicable at a time for statistics"
      },
      {
        "keyword": "errorMessage",
        "dataPath": "/statistics",
        "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/1/errorMessage",
        "params": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "keyword": "not",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/1/then/not",
              "params": {},
              "message": "should NOT be valid"
            },
            {
              "keyword": "if",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/1/if",
              "params": {
                "failingKeyword": "then"
              },
              "message": "should match \"then\" schema"
            }
          ]
        },
        "message": "Only Finland applicable at a time for statistics"
      },
      {
        "keyword": "errorMessage",
        "dataPath": "/statistics",
        "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/2/errorMessage",
        "params": {
          "errors": [
            {
              "keyword": "not",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/2/then/not",
              "params": {},
              "message": "should NOT be valid"
            },
            {
              "keyword": "if",
              "dataPath": "/statistics",
              "schemaPath": "#/properties/statistics/allOf/2/if",
              "params": {
                "failingKeyword": "then"
              },
              "message": "should match \"then\" schema"
            }
          ]
        },
        "message": "Only Germany applicable at a time for statistics"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already deduced it yourself: the `allOf` `contains` applies all subschemas and checks against all array items.

If you want only one error message, then you should decide the priority of countries and only check in subsequent `allOf` parts for the remaining countries and not all of them each time. E.g.

1. If the array contains a “USA” entry, neither “GERMANY” nor “FINLAND” should be present (as you already have it)
2. If the array contains a “GERMANY” entry, no “FINLAND” entry should be present (do **not** check for “USA” again)
3. If the array contains a “FINLAND” entry, the possible scenarios are already covered by the two checks above – no need for any additional check here.

That way, you never get multiple of these errors at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But in the broader case, if I have a large entries in the array and that gets checked against allOf, the chances are, there would be that number of error messages and that is inevitable to avoid. Also, what is the best way to deliver such error message back to the caller in a cleaner way (although I am using ajv-errors npm) ?

Comment: Not sure about improving how the validation errors are presented. However, you could also embrace the multiple error messages being returned and just rephrase them to something like “multiple countries found where only one is allowed. found: USA” and the return the same error for each type (in the same way you have it now).

Comment: Another alternative would be to use `oneOf` instead of `allOf`. You’d still have multiple error messages, but they would clearly state that there are multiple valid entries in `oneOf`. Each entry could be defined as “array contains(X) and not(contains(anything but X))” – with an extra “array is empty” case if that’s allowed.

Comment: Thanks @Carsten. Will try oneOf option